# C# universal windows app detect face from ip camera

Tags: c#, uwp, camera, ip

I am developing an Universal Windows App using c# and XAML. And my require is using IP camera to detect Face. 
I have reference to https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CameraFaceDetection. But i want to replace integrate webcam to IP Camera. Now i don't know how to connect to IP Camera, so Anybody give me some advices to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

With the corresponding capabilities configuration in your Package.appxmanifest file,

```
  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <Capability Name="privateNetworkClientServer" />
    <Capability Name="internetClientServer" />
    <DeviceCapability Name="webcam" />
  </Capabilities>
```

You can use the following code to get the ip camera data,

```
Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream random = 
    await Windows.Storage.Streams.RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromUri(new Uri("your device uri")).OpenReadAsync();

Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(random);
Windows.Graphics.Imaging.PixelDataProvider pixelData = await decoder.GetPixelDataAsync();

byte[] bytes = pixelData.DetachPixelData();
```

Note that: you should consult or find the camera manufacturer for `your device uri` in above code.